# Is it possible to toggle individual USB ports?

Tags: usb, usb-power

I have a motion-detecting PiCamera set up running, which is fine and dandy until it gets dark. I *could* get another Pi with the NoIR camera instead, but a simple solution occurred to me the other day - plug in a USB light designed for using laptops in the dark, and have the Pi turn that on when it detects motion.

However, that is predicated on the possibility of the Pi allowing individual ports to be activated and deactivated. Is that possible, either in the terminal or using Python? If not, how easy would it be to do with the GPIO system?

Comment: There appear to be mixed answers regarding software to control USB power on Linux based, you might have to wire up a physical relay. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/727195-disable-a-enable-usb-from-terminal http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13281/disable-usb-power-for-usb-controlled-power-strip http://askubuntu.com/questions/342061/power-on-off-usb-ports http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163824/linux-usb-turning-the-power-on-and-off . Keep us posted.

Comment: Hmmm. Running a few of the commands shown in those threads suggests that both on-board USB ports are the same device, so disabling it would disable _all_ USB devices connected to the Pi. As I use a WiFi dongle, that makes it something of a non-starter. Perhaps my first GPIO project will be adding a light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible (at least on the model B I'm familiar with, you can check the schematics for others) to toggle the USB VBus power, as there are no power switching devices on the board to implement this, and USB lights typically use only (abuse) the USB power without being command-able over the data lines.

It's true that a few USB hub implementations provide per-port power switching (many hub chips have the output pins to drive power switching FET's, but few hub PCB's have the FET's installed), and there may be ways to command them under Linux, but that's not relevant to an implementation where they are not present.

You should be able to accomplish your goal with a USB- or GPIO- commanded switching device - FET or transistor driver, mechanical or solid state relay, etc.   These are available both as bare components or already packaged on a board/module, direct wired or opto-isolated, etc.  If buying a USB-connected device, be sure to get one where driver source code is available either from the vendor or someone who has reverse engineered it, as neither a windows driver nor a binary-only x86 linux one would be much use on the pi.